# OnetoOne Bi-directional Association Error on using referenceColumnName

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

**Company Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="company")

public class Company implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    @Column(name="company_id")
    private int cmpId;

    @Column(name="company_name")
    private String companyName;

    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="company")
    private Employee employee;




}
```

**Employee Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="employee")
public class Employee implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    @Column(name="emp_id")
    private int empId;

    @Column(name="emp_name")
    private String empName;

    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="cmp_id", referencedColumnName="company_id")
    private Company company;

}
```

**Company Service**

```
@Service
public class CompanyService {

    @Autowired
    private CompanyRepository companyRepo;

    public Company fetchCompany(int cmpId){
        System.out.println("11111111111111111");
        return companyRepo.findByCmpId(cmpId);
    }
}
```

**Company Repo**

```
public interface CompanyRepository extends JpaRepository<Company, Integer>{ 

    @Query(value="select a from Company a join fetch a.employee where a.cmpId = ?1")
    public Company findByCmpId(int cmpId);
}
```

**API**

```
@RequestMapping("/cmp/{cmpId}")
public void findCmp(@PathVariable int cmpId){
    Company cmp = cmpService.fetchCompany(cmpId);
    System.out.println(cmp.getEmployee().getEmpName());
}
```

Issue is when I am trying to execute my code, I am getting following error:

```
  Hibernate: select company0_.id as id1_1_0_, employee1_.id as id1_2_1_, company0_.company_id as company_2_1_0_, company0_.company_name as company_3_1_0_, employee1_.cmp_id as cmp_id4_2_1_, employee1_.emp_id as emp_id2_2_1_, employee1_.emp_name as emp_name3_2_1_ from company company0_ inner join employee employee1_ on company0_.id=employee1_.cmp_id where company0_.company_id=?
2017-04-21 17:22:11.386 ERROR 10766 --- [nio-8105-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Error accessing field [private int com.example.domain.Company.cmpId] by reflection for persistent property [com.example.domain.Company#cmpId] : 1; nested exception is org.hibernate.property.access.spi.PropertyAccessException: Error accessing field [private int com.example.domain.Company.cmpId] by reflection for persistent property [com.example.domain.Company#cmpId] : 1] with root cause

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set int field com.example.domain.Company.cmpId to java.lang.Integer
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:58) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeIntegerFieldAccessorImpl.getInt(UnsafeIntegerFieldAccessorImpl.java:56) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeIntegerFieldAccessorImpl.get(UnsafeIntegerFieldAccessorImpl.java:36) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:393) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
```

How to fix this? Also when I have removed **referenceColumnName**, then the error is removed but them it is joining with primary key of company class, which I dont want.?

Comment: have you solved this and how?

Comment: @Ankit Bansal Did you find a solution to this issue, I am facing the same problem, and I haven't been able to solve it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks a bit funky, but I believe it works the way you requested.

**Company**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "company")
public class Company implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "comp_id")
    private Integer compId;

    @Column(name = "company_name")
    private String companyName;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="emp_id", referencedColumnName="emp_id")
    private Employee employee;

    @PostPersist
    public void postPersist() {
        if (id != null && compId == null) {
            setCompId(new Integer(id));
        }
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getCompanyName() {
        return companyName;
    }

    public void setCompanyName(String companyName) {
        this.companyName = companyName;
    }

    public Employee getEmployee() {
        return employee;
    }

    public void setEmployee(Employee employee) {
        this.employee = employee;
    }

    public Integer getCompId() {
        return compId;
    }

    public void setCompId(Integer compId) {
        this.compId = compId;
    }
}
```

**CompanyRepository**

```
public interface CompanyRepository extends JpaRepository<Company, Integer> {

    @Query(value = "select a from Company a join fetch a.employee as emp where a.compId = ?1")
    public Company findByCmpId(int cmpId);
}
```

**CompanyService**

```
@Service
public class CompanyService {

    @Autowired
    private CompanyRepository companyRepo;

    public Company fetchCompany(int cmpId) {
        return companyRepo.findByCmpId(cmpId);
    }
}
```

**Employee**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "emp_id")
    private Integer empId;

    @Column(name = "emp_name")
    private String empName;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="comp_id", referencedColumnName="comp_id")
    private Company company;

    @PostPersist
    public void postPersist() {
        if (id != null && empId == null) {
            setEmpId(new Integer(id));
        }
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getEmpId() {
        return empId;
    }

    public void setEmpId(Integer empId) {
        this.empId = empId;
    }

    public String getEmpName() {
        return empName;
    }

    public void setEmpName(String empName) {
        this.empName = empName;
    }

    public Company getCompany() {
        return company;
    }

    public void setCompany(Company company) {
        this.company = company;
    }
}
```

**EmployeeRepository**

```
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Integer> 
{
    @Query(value = "select a from Employee a join fetch a.company as comp where a.empId = ?1")
    public Employee findByEmpId(int cmpId);
}
```

**EmployeeService**

```
@Service
public class EmployeeService {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeRepository employeeRepo;

    public Employee fetchEmployee(int empId) {
        return employeeRepo.findByEmpId(empId);
    }
}
```

**Unit Tests**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class RnlApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    CompanyService companyService;

    @Autowired
    EmployeeService employeeService;

    @Autowired
    CompanyRepository companyRepository;

    @Autowired
    EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

    @Before 
    public void setup() {
        Employee employee = new Employee();
        employee.setEmpName("Test Employee");

        Company company = new Company();
        company.setCompanyName("Test Company");
        company = companyRepository.save(company);

        employee.setCompany(company);
        employee = employeeRepository.save(employee);

        company.setEmployee(employee);
        company = companyRepository.save(company);

        Employee employee2 = new Employee();
        employee2.setEmpName("Test Employee2");

        Company company2 = new Company();
        company2.setCompanyName("Test Company2");
        company2 = companyRepository.save(company2);

        employee2.setCompany(company2);
        employee2 = employeeRepository.save(employee2);

        company2.setEmployee(employee2);
        company2 = companyRepository.save(company2);
    }

    @Test
    public void testRepository() {
        Company company = companyService.fetchCompany(1);
        assertThat(company).isNotNull();

        Company company2 = companyService.fetchCompany(2);
        assertThat(company2).isNotNull();

        Employee employee = employeeService.fetchEmployee(1);
        assertThat(employee).isNotNull();

        Employee employee2 = employeeService.fetchEmployee(2);
        assertThat(employee2).isNotNull();
    }
}
```

The setup for the test is a bit repetitive, but I had to set it up that way to get these test cases working.  You can probably figure out a better way.

**Hibernate SQL output from Company test**

```
select
    company0_.id as id1_0_2_,
    company0_.comp_id as comp_id2_0_2_,
    company0_.company_name as company_3_0_2_,
    company0_.emp_id as emp_id4_0_2_,
    employee1_.id as id1_1_0_,
    employee1_.comp_id as comp_id4_1_0_,
    employee1_.emp_id as emp_id2_1_0_,
    employee1_.emp_name as emp_name3_1_0_,
    company2_.id as id1_0_1_,
    company2_.comp_id as comp_id2_0_1_,
    company2_.company_name as company_3_0_1_,
    company2_.emp_id as emp_id4_0_1_ 
from
    company company0_ 
left outer join
    employee employee1_ 
        on company0_.emp_id=employee1_.emp_id 
left outer join
    company company2_ 
        on employee1_.comp_id=company2_.comp_id 
where
    company0_.comp_id=?
```

**Hibernate SQL output from Employee test**

```
select
    employee0_.id as id1_1_0_,
    company1_.id as id1_0_1_,
    employee0_.comp_id as comp_id4_1_0_,
    employee0_.emp_id as emp_id2_1_0_,
    employee0_.emp_name as emp_name3_1_0_,
    company1_.comp_id as comp_id2_0_1_,
    company1_.company_name as company_3_0_1_,
    company1_.emp_id as emp_id4_0_1_ 
from
    employee employee0_ 
inner join
    company company1_ 
        on employee0_.comp_id=company1_.comp_id 
where
    employee0_.emp_id=?
```

Comment: Try changing the referenced column to a datatype such as String. Would it still work? I only have the issue on non Integer types.

Answer (score 1):

Exception :

```
 IllegalArgumentException: Can not set int field com.example.domain.Company.cmpId to java.lang.Integer
```

Please use Integer`instead` of `int` in Company  as we as in Employee entity if id field.

```
 @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;
```

Also please provide getter and setter methods for fields in your entity.

Comment: No effect. I have changed the id field of both Entity to Integer. Same error. Also if you see the trace, the exception is coming in case of cmpId field not for primary key. I have changed it to Integer but same error, then error changes to cannot changes the Integer to Integer.

Answer (score 1):

```
**Can not set int field com.example.domain.Company.cmpId to java.lang.Integer**

Hibernate except foreign key of employee table cmp_id, should be primary key of company. But in your code cmpId is not primary key.

        @Column(name="company_id")
        private int cmpId;

Please make that primary and check once.


Edited:-
1.
        @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="company")
        private Employee employee;
change to:-
        @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="company",optional=false)
        private Employee employee;

2.
        @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name="cmp_id", referencedColumnName="company_id")
        private Company company;
change to:-
        @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name="cmp_id")
        private Company company;
```

Comment: But I have to work with Database where I cannot have that. Can't I use it without that? Join on Non-Primary Key using referenceColumnName

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37047938/jpa-hibernate-onetoone-joincolumn-referencedcolumnname-ignored                                                  Hope will be useful.

Comment: This answer is not suitable. I have already told that I have to made join on non-primary key column. Your edited solution will only make join with primary key of company table instead of company_id.

Comment: It will also work with non-primary key. I checked it.

Comment: this is wat I dont understand. Where in this code you have mentioned that join needs to be JoinColumn from table Employee us cmp_id and table Company is company_id. You have just specified that it will join cmp_id of employee table to PRIMARY KEY(id) of compnay table but in my case I need to join cmp_id of employee table to NON-PRIMARY KEY(company_id) of company table