# Spring boot Jpa Entity, map same referenced column as id and entity

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have two tables user and student. Student and user has one to one relationship.
I am mapping same column with both userId and UserEntity inside StudentEntity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {
    @Id
    private UUID id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    ...

    // getter setter ignored for brevity
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
public class Student {
    @Id
    private UUID id;

    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private UUID userId;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id", 
                insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private UserEntity userEntity;

    ...

    // getter setter ignored for brevity
}
```

```
@Repository
public interface StudentRepository extend PagingAndSortingRepository<StudentEntity, UUID> {

  Optional<StudentEntity> findByUserId(UUID userId);
}
```

Now when I call any of below method UserEntity is not populated

```
StudentEntity student = studentRepository.findByUserId(userId).get()
student.getUserId() --- this is present
student.getUserEntity() -- NULL
```

Not sure why UserEntity is not getting populated as a part of this call.

Comment: Your code works for me. Can you please show the whole method? Do you save and find the User in the same transaction?

Comment: Remove this field   @Column(name = "user_id")
    private UUID userId;

And it should work

Comment: By specifying the user_id in the JoinColumn annotation makes everything correctly work.
There is no need of seperate field for userId in your entity

Comment: The thing is I need both so that in spring boot I can use findByUserId() and findByUserEntity()

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I tried both same and different transactions its still null

Comment: @big could you have findByUserId passing userEntity.getId and findByUserEntity passing the full userEntity?

Comment: will anything happen if you move insertable = false, updatable = false from userEntity to userId?

Comment: I tried moving it to userId but then userId field will be null. It seems like one field will always null if I go this route.

Comment: Please show your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is most likely that your persistence context still contains the entity that you previously saved (which has no user set). You would first have to clear the persistence context and the load it again to see a non-null user.

Anyway, like suggested in the comments, I would advise you to just map the user. You don't need the `userId` field. The way you mapped it now, you should be able to use the following:

```
Optional<StudentEntity> findByUserEntityId(UUID userId);
```

Also read the official documentation for more information on the matter: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-property-expressions

Comment: Yes, this will work, but now when I want to save a new student entity then I have to pass complete UserEntity inside StudentEntity Object. If userId is part of this class then I will not need that and can just pass userId. I don't have to make another db call just to get complete UserEntity

Comment: You don't have to, you can use `EntityManager.getReference` to avoid the database call. I think in spring this is surfaced through the `getOne` method in repositories

Comment: So getOne works for me. Thanks this is what I was looking to achieve

Answer (score -1):

You can try reverse mapping mapping like below by using mappedby in the owner of the relationship
[jpa hibernate @OneToOne @JoinColumn referencedColumnName ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37047938/jpa-hibernate-onetoone-joincolumn-referencedcolumnname-ignored)